# read.table and apply functions to a column

Tags: apache, class, r

I am reading an apache logfile using read.table and am wondering if it's somehow possible to apply a function (i.e. strptime ) while the data are being imported, instead of post-processing it.

More details as requested:
The column containing the date has the format:

```
[10/Nov/2011:06:25:14
```

I can successfully parse it using:

```
strptime(red[1,4],format="[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S")
```

or

```
as.POSIXct(strptime(red[1,4],format="[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S"))
```

but

```
as.POSIXct(red[1,4],format="[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S")
```

fails. Hence I cannot use POSIXct in colClasses AFAIK.

Comment: Writing a function that simply does both (read the file and then process columns) would be functionally equivalent.

Comment: I'm trying to be as efficient as possible since the data to process are a lot.

Comment: Why do you think a function that calls read.table and then manually does the date coercion would be inefficient? If you'd taken that route, you'd probably be done by now. ;)

Comment: i would strongly recommend keeping the `read` and `clean` operations separate. tampering with the `raw` data without having saved it in the first place can give you a lot of grief if you go back and realize there is a bug. not sure, what other users think, but i think a good workflow would separate the two. and as @joran indicated, i don't think it would be any less efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is an `as.` method you can use colClasses with that class. Since Date is a class and has a default format of YYYY-MM-DD, if your dates are in that format, you could just include Date in the `colClasses` vector. It is also possible to define new `as.function`'s. As always, the more detail you supply about the problem, the better the answer.

```
 library(methods)
 setClass("logDate")
#[1] "logDate"
 setAs("character", "logDate", function(from) 
                              as.POSIXct(from, format="[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S"))
 DF <- read.table(text="[10/Nov/2011:06:25:14", header = FALSE,
                            colClasses = c("logDate"))
 str(DF)
#'data.frame':  1 obs. of  1 variable:
# $ V1: POSIXct, format: "2011-11-10 06:25:14"
```

Should probably give Gabor Grothendieck some credit since he is the one who showed me how to do this 5 years ago:
https://www.stat.math.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-April/130912.html

Comment: I've edited the question to add more details, thanks for your input.

Comment: Thanks. I'll make the easy fix.

Comment: Since R 2.14, yo can use `text` argument which makes `textConnection` in combination with `read.table` obsolete. FWIW. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this, probably, you could define the desired format for Your log. So don't need to postprocess Your data, if it will come already in good format.

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
CustomLog logs/access_log common
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/logs.html#accesslog
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_log_config.html

Comment: I'm planning to do so, but I have a lot of legacy data I have to manage.

Comment: Probably some sed/awk on existing logs could help in Your case.