Specify factor levels while reading in data (not afterwards!)
I have data that I read into a dataframe specifying colClasses, e.g.:
dat <- read.table(textConnection("
One Two
D 1
B 2
A 3
C 4
"), header = TRUE, colClasses = c("factor", "integer"))

If levels aren't specified, R orders them alphabetically:
str(dat)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ One: Factor w/ 4 levels "A","B","C","D": 4 2 1 3
 $ Two: int  1 2 3 4

If I want the levels to be in a different order, for example in the order the values appear –
 $ One: Factor w/ 4 levels "D","B","A","C": 1 2 3 4

– how can I specify this in the command that reads in the data?
I do not want to reorder the levels!!
I do not want to do:
dat$One <- factor(dat$One, levels = c("D","B","A","C"))


Have a look at custom factor class: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880532/how-to-specify-the-ordering-of-categorical-variables-in-read-csv-in-r. To have values in  appearing order: SpecifyOrders <- function(from) { from <- factor(from, levels = unique(from)) }

You can do this with readr functions.
library(readr)

custom_order <- c("D", "B", "A", "C")
out <- read_delim("One Two
D 1
B 2
A 3
C 4", col_types = cols(One = col_factor(custom_order), Two = col_integer()))

levels(out$One)

[1] "D" "B" "A" "C"

col_factor() by default takes the order of the data in which they appear. So in this case using only col_factor() would also work.
